# Codeigniter form_dropdown error in form_helper at line 331

Tags: codeigniter

I'm new to codeigniter and i wanted to create a form using form_dropdown. I already tried lots of ideas from others but is simply doesn't make it right. I wanted to recreate my online hotel reservation project using codeigniter because wamp server 2 doesn't support mysql extensions anymore and i want to learn more about PHP using frameworks:

here is my model:

```
public function room_options()
        {
            $query = $this->db->get('room_type');

            if($query->num_rows() > 0)
            {
                foreach($query->result() as $row)
                {
                    $data[$row->room_type_id] = $row->room_type_name;
                }
                return $data;
            }
        }

        public function check_rooms($room_type)
        { 
            $this->db->where('room_type_id', $room_type);
            $this->db->where('`room_id` NOT IN (SELECT `room_id` FROM `reservation`)', NULL, FALSE);
            $query = $this->db->get('room');
            var_dump($this->db->queries);

            if($query->num_rows() > 0)
            {
                foreach($query->result() as $row)
                {
                    $data[$row->room_id] = $row->room_name;
                }
                return $data[0];
            }
        }
```

here is my controller:

```
public function welcome_page($page = 'welcome_page')
{
    if ($this->session->userdata('is_logged_in'))
    {
    if(! file_exists('application/views/'.$page.'.php'))
    {
        show_404();
    }
            $this->load->model('check_availability_model');
            $data['options'] = $this->check_availability_model->room_options();
            $this->load->view('includes/member_header');
            $this->load->view('includes/member_navigation');
    $this->load->view(''.$page, $data);
            $this->load->view('includes/member_footer');
    }
    else
    {
    redirect('member/restricted');
    }
}

public function restricted()
{
    $this->load->view('restricted');
}

public function register($page = 'register')
{
    if(! file_exists('application/views/'.$page.'.php'))
    {
        show_404();
    }
    $this->load->view('includes/header');
    $this->load->view(''.$page);
    $this->load->view('includes/header');
}

    public function check_reservation()
    {
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('room_type', 'Room Type', 'required|trim|xss_clean|callback_reserve_credentials');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('checkin_date', 'Checkin Date', 'required|trim|xss_clean');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('checkout_date', 'Checkout Date', 'required|trim|xss_clean');

        if($this->form_validation->run()==FALSE)
        {
            $this->load->model('check_availability_model');
            $data['options'] = $this->check_availability_model->room_options();
            $this->load->view('includes/member_header');
            $this->load->view('includes/member_navigation');
    $this->load->view('welcome_page', $data);
            $this->load->view('includes/member_footer');
        }
        else
        {
            redirect('member/reservation_form');
        }
    }

    public function reserve_credentials()
    {
        $this->load->model('check_availability_model');
        if($this->check_availability_model->check_rooms($this->input->post('room_type')))
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            $this->form_validation->set_message('reserve_credentials', 'The room is not available at this time. Please choose another.');
            return false;
        }
    }

public function reservation_form($page = 'reservation_form')
{
    if ($this->session->userdata('is_logged_in'))
    {
    if(! file_exists('application/views/'.$page.'.php'))
    {
        show_404();
    }
            $this->load->library('subquery');
            $this->load->model('check_availability_model');
            $data['options'] = $this->check_availability_model->check_rooms($this->input->post('room_type'));
            $this->load->view('includes/member_header');
            $this->load->view('includes/member_navigation');
    $this->load->view(''.$page, $data);
            $this->load->view('includes/member_footer');
    }
    else
    {
    redirect('member/restricted');
    }
}
```

and my view:

```
    <?php echo form_open('member/check_reservation', array('class' => 'form col-md-12 center-block', 'role' => 'search'));?>
    <?php echo form_dropdown('room_name', $options, set_value('room_name'), 'class="form-control input-lg"');?>
    <p></p>
    <?php echo form_submit('register_submit', 'Register', "class='btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block'");?>
    <p></p>
    <?php echo validation_errors();?>
    <?php echo form_close();?>
```

The user will select the room type and the dates. then it will be redirected to another form that the user will select again a room name from what room type did the user selected earlier. I tried to var_dump the query and it says:

0 => string 'SELECT *
FROM (`room`)
WHERE `room_type_id` =  0
AND `room_id` NOT IN (SELECT `room_id` FROM `reservation`)' (length=107)

$this->input->post('room_type') has to be read.

```
Your help will really be appreciated. Thank you very much.


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3wAy2.png
```

Comment: Are you sure you're getting anything from the database? In your model, try and var_dump the database results.

Comment: yep, i tried the var_dump. it says:  0 => string 'SELECT *
FROM (`room`)
WHERE `room_type_id` =  0
AND `room_id` NOT IN (SELECT `room_id` FROM `reservation`)' (length=107)

Comment: on the previous form. the user will try to select the type of room. then, it will redirected to another view which i posted earlier. so this time, the user again will select the room name of the selected room type. Thanks for replying very fast craig. thanks for mentioning the var_dump function. It really helps

Comment: You're welcome. Did you fix the problem?

Comment: not yet. I will edit my post to clarify.

Comment: I still can't get anything from the database. what can i do in order to read the $this->input->post('room_type') from the query.

Comment: Did you fix this problem?

Comment: yeah, i already fix it. thanks, I will post my answer. Feel free to suggest if you have one. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
  else
    {
        return false;
    }
```

you need to return an empty array here.

Comment: hi, thank you for replying. I think my query is the error. I tried using var_dump and it says that room_typ_id = 0 which is not supposed to be 0. i forget to tell you the scenario: on the previous form. the user will try to select the type of room. then, it will redirected to another view which i posted earlier. so this time, the user again will select the room name of the selected room type.

Comment: still, the else should not return false because that will cause the function form_dropdown to crash...

Comment: should i leave it blank or comment the else statement?

Answer (score 0):

Try these few changes... Instead of using the post() function inside the model, pass it through as a parameter on the `check_rooms()`;

```
public function check_rooms($room_type)
```

You can now use this in your `$db->where()`

```
$this->db->where('room_type_id', $room_type);
```

**The controller...**

```
$data['options'] = $this->check_availability_model->check_rooms($this->input->post('room_type'));
```

You should also return the first index of your data array, from your model;

```
return $data[0];
```

View the page source when loaded in the browser, and check the form values are correct.

Hope this helps.

Comment: i tried to echo $this->input->post('room_type') inside else statement at check_reservation controller then it reads the echo but inside if statement at reservation_form controller it didn't read. how can i pass $this->input->post('room_type') from reservation_form controller.

Answer (score 0):

So, after two days of debugging and finally have the answer to my post. Since $this->input->post('room_type') can't be read on reservation_form and i need to pass the variable:

I have a few changes at controller:

```
public function check_reservation()
{
     $this->load->library('form_validation');
     $this->form_validation->set_rules('room_type', 'Room Type', 'required|trim|xss_clean|callback_reserve_credentials');
     $this->form_validation->set_rules('checkin_date', 'Checkin Date', 'required|trim|xss_clean');
     $this->form_validation->set_rules('checkout_date', 'Checkout Date', 'required|trim|xss_clean');

     if($this->form_validation->run()==FALSE)
     {
         $this->load->model('check_availability_model');
         $data['options'] = $this->check_availability_model->room_options();
         $this->load->view('includes/member_header');
         $this->load->view('includes/member_navigation');
         $this->load->view('welcome_page', $data);
         $this->load->view('includes/member_footer');
     }
     else
     {
         //so here is the change
         //redirect('member/reservation_form');
         $room_type = $this->reservation_form($this->input->post('room_type'));
     }
   }

public function reservation_form($room_type)//$this->input->post('room_type') can now be read by passing the parameter $room_type
{
    if ($this->session->userdata('is_logged_in'))
    {
    if(! file_exists('application/views/reservation_form.php'))
    {
        show_404();
    }
            $this->load->library('subquery');
            $this->load->model('check_availability_model');
            $data['options'] = $this->check_availability_model->check_rooms();
            $this->load->view('includes/member_header');
            $this->load->view('includes/member_navigation');
    $this->load->view('reservation_form', $data);
            $this->load->view('includes/member_footer');
    }
    else
    {
    redirect('member/restricted');
    }
}
```

and my model is still the same:

```
    public function check_rooms()
    {   
        $this->db->where('room_type_id', $this->input->post('room_type'));
        $this->db->where('`room_id` NOT IN (SELECT `room_id` FROM `reservation`)', NULL, FALSE);
        $query = $this->db->get('room');

        if($query->num_rows() > 0)
        {
            foreach($query->result() as $row)
            {
                $data[$row->room_id] = $row->room_name;
            }
            return $data;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Please feel free to add some suggestions if you had any better than my answer. I've also been looking forward to make my code as shortcut as possible. Thank you once again :)